# Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 WebhookResponse unable to close conversation

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I am very new to the Google Api and Dialogflow, as such I started by doing the walkthrough using node.js and the codelabs on their website.

Now the time has come to remove the training wheels so I wanting to use a C# Azure hosted webhook solution, this fits in with my companies architecture and that we're .Net focused developers.

I started using the Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 project which enables me to quickly get the request object and create a response, however I can find very little documentation and for cannot get the correct response to end a conversation using the expectUserResponse tag.

Here is what I have, this correctly returns the text but the conversation remains open

```
response = new WebhookResponse
{
    FulfillmentText = $"Your magic number is {magicNumber}.",
    Payload = new Struct
    {
        Fields = {
                    {"expectUserResponse", new Value()
                        {
                           BoolValue = false
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
};
```

The jSon this writes is

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Your magic number is 6.",
  "payload": {
    "expectUserResponse": false
  }
}
```

If I manually alter the return json to this, it works.

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Your magic number is 6.",
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": false
    }
  }
}
```

So the question is how do I make get the correct return json using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `payload` to be a map containing a `google` field which is itself a struct.

Here's a complete example that does that - and shows how the factory methods in `Value` make it simpler to use too:

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;
using Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var googlePayload = new Struct
        {
            Fields = { { "expectUserPayload", Value.ForBool(false) } }
        };
        var response = new WebhookResponse
        {
            FulfillmentText = $"Your magic number is 100.",
            Payload = new Struct
            {
                Fields = { { "google", Value.ForStruct(googlePayload) } }
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

Output (reformatted):

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Your magic number is 100.",
  "payload": { "google": { "expectUserPayload": false } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, amazingly enough I just figured out literally 5 minutes ago!

Cheers